# NURB curves with interior knot multiplicy higher than curve degree

Tags: curves, bezier-curve

I have the following question. If I have a NURB curve where one of the interior knots has multiplicity higher than the degree of curve (I did not chose to have such curves, I am writing a code for importing CAD drawings and there is a possibility of such ill defined cases) what does this unnecessary multiplicity do to the control points. In the specific example I have, I see that it results in multiplicity of the control points at the those knot values. For example, if I have a curve of degree $p$, and a internal knot $u$ of multiplicity $p+1$ this results in control point coinciding with the curve value at $u$ to have multiplicity two. Now, would this always be the case? Or is it just a coincidence. Because if it is always the case, I can just remove the knot until I have multiplicity $p$ and remove the corresponding control point corresponding amount of times and get a well parametrized curve. In case this is not always true, how would you suggest me to reduce the knots to get a curve where the knot vector does not have internal knots of multiplicity higher than the curve degree? I though maybe one could do curve degree elevation, but then again, I would somehow have to add knots and the end of knot vector (for them to have multiplicity of $degree+1$) and this seems somehow redundant.

Thank you very much for your help and time,
Donatas

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the exact problem a few times when importing DXF files. The problematic B-spline curve in DXF file is of degree 3 and has interior knots of multiplicity 4. Luckily for such B-spline curves I had encountered they always have coincident control point at the knot value. Therefore, I can simply remove the extra knot and ignore the duplicated control point during importing. When the control points are not coincident, the B-spline curve data does not really represent a single curve and you will have to import the B-spline curve as multiple curves.

Suppose the B-spline curve you want to import is of degree 3 with knot sequence $[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1]$. This curve would have 8 control points $P_0,P_1$ ~ $P_7$. When $P_3$ and $P_4$ are not identical, you can import it as two curves, with first curve defined by $P_0$~$P_3$ and 2nd one defined by $P_4$~$P_7$.

Comment: Thank you, its good to know that some one experiences the same problem. That exactly was my strategy. But could you explain bit more the second part of your answer, importing B-spline curve data as multiple B-spline curves? How you chose the corresponding control points and knots for each of the curves?

Comment: More details added.